# Extending or Overriding a foreign BaseClass to add functionality that is then also present in foreign child classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, selenium

Okay this is hard to explain and I have been struggling with it several times over the last years now. I'm sure there must be a pattern for doing it in some way but I sadly am not aware of it.

Having a base class and several child classes of a foreign library (today it is about selenium) I want to introduce some helper methods within the base class (using the methods already present) that will then be also available in the foreign child classes that extend this class.

A concrete example:

The `WebDriver` class of Selenium offers a method `findElement` to find elements in the DOM. In the end a specific `WebDriver` e.g. (`ChromeDriver` or `FirefoxDriver`) has to be used that all subclass `WebDriver`.

Having said that I want to extend `WebDriver` with some convience methods that can then be used with all subclassing drivers. E.g. I would like to inject a `findElementTimeout` method that contains more or less just something like that:

`manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(milliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
WebElement element = findElement(selector);
manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0    , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
return element;`

In fact its not at all about Selenium but a very general use case. Changing parent classes of foreign software using the already given methods. Can anyone point me to the general solution that is used in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically modify classes in Java without resorting to bytecode instrumentation. The general software-engineering solution used in this case is the *decorator* pattern.

You can create a stateless wrapper class that takes the base-class as a single constructor argument e.g:

```
 public class WebDriverDecorator {
      public final WebDriver webDriver;

      public WebDriverDecorator(WebDriver wd) {
          this.webDriver = wd;
      } 

      // add your conveniece methods here
 }
```

Then, in subclasses, or anywhere else, where you have an instance of WebDriver, you can decorate it with WebDriverDecorator and invoke your convenience methods:

```
WebDriver wd = ....;
WebDriverDecorator wdd = new WebDriverDecorator(wd);
wdd.yourMethodCallGoesHere();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I knew about this pattern but I thought there must be another way.

Comment: You can also use Virtual Extension Methods in Java 8, but I haven't tried them yet. Then you could derive your classes from both WebDriver and an interface containing extension methods.